# I2C Relay Circuit shorting & sparking

Tags: relay, i2c, short-circuit

I'm having trouble diagnosing a faulty circuit. Here's the schematic, which is based on [this instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/I2C-Relay-Board/) build. This is part of a bigger circuit, but I have tested it in isolation on a fresh board.

[image]

[Link to the Eagle file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UCL_9sBZW5kzw0BAXi1tL_ALA1Mc64l/view?usp=sharing) (This is part of a bigger board, but hopefully this helps)

The purpose of the circuit is to drive 16 relays using I2C communication. I'm currently testing with an Arduino Mega. I'm using the [MCP23017](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP23017T-E-SS/MCP23017T-E-SSCT-ND/5013524) for the 16 I/O pins, and two [ULN2803ADWR](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/ULN2803ADWR/296-15777-1-ND/598088) darling transistor arrays to sink 5v on each [G5Q-14 DC5](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5Q-14-DC5/Z2929-ND/1815716) relay coil.

The circuit seems to be correct – I've gotten it to run a few times and the Arduino can successfully switch the relay. After less than a minute or so, pins 9 and 10 on the MCP (+5v and GND) start sparking and smoking. I've tested this on two PCBs meticulously testing for shorts between pins before turning it on - same issue. I also only encounter this issue once introducing the relay to the circuit.

I also find that pins 9 and 10 become connected after the sparking occurs. Not until I apply the soldering iron do they go back to being disconnected. Is it common that very close pins will bond when things get that hot?

I have no idea what's causing this short. Does it seem like a physical error or a circuit design error?

Note that:

- In my circuit, the MCP is floating on A0 A1 A2 (address pins). Does this matter?
- On my PCB, the MCP pin 9 (+5v) is connected after the relay coils (the trace goes from the +5v source, through each coil, then to the MCP). Could that be causing an issue?

Comment: I notice you don't seem to have flyback diodes antiparallel with any relay coils. If you power up your board but make the software not switch relays, does it still fry? Any inductance (like a relay coil) produces a voltage spike whenever current in it is interrupted. Inductors want to keep current flowing through them the same so they produce a voltage to oppose the current if it's increasing which gets stored in the magnet field. When the current decreases, the inductor dumps the energy in the magnetic field to push the current through the obstacle. If it's a big obstacle (like an open relay)

Comment: [cont...] then the inductor produces whatever voltage is required to shove the current through that until the energy in its magnetic field is exhausted. That spike can is appears on the 5V you are using to power the relay coil, which also happens to be what is powering your MCU. Chances are it's frying your MCU and semiconductors tend to fail short-circuit rather than open circuit which would cause the overheating and frying. The spike is probably damaging the ULN2803s as well but it's not as evident since they can tolerate up to 50V.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the ULN2803s include such diodes within them. I'm not sure I trust those however. If you have a scope you can scope the line to check if the spike on the 5V rail is being suppressed enough.

Comment: are you saying that an electric arc occurs between pin 9 and 10 of the MCP23017?

Comment: @Toor Your explanation seems plausible to me. Regarding built in diodes: they do the job as long they have connection, so if you don't remove or plug the relay when it is energized.

Comment: @Toor I agree this seems possible. I will try not switching the relays to see what happens. It seems that that little bit of inductance might be sparking the IC and the heat is immediately connecting the pins, causing further damage. The very first time I plugged this in, I saw tiny sparks on MCP pins 9 and 10 at every relay switch, but the pins weren't becoming bonded yet.

Comment: @jstola yes, between 9 and 10 of the MCP23017

Comment: Can we get a photo of pins 9 and 10? Is the PCB clean there? It doesn't sound like the clamp diode inside the relay driver is doing its job.

Comment: Usually missing flyback diodes seem to silently damage chips - I'm impressed that you got *actual sparks* from this problem, if it is indeed the problem.

Comment: @immibis haha I know, right?!

Comment: @toor Yes I can take some tomorrow. The MCP is a SSOP chip so the pins are extremely close together. There was definitely some flux residue which may have conducted? I resoldered it about 6 times today and it sparked each time the relay was introduced. I am now thinking of just going with a relay board isolated with opticouplers [like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kuman-Channel-Shield-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B014L10Q52/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) to save me from worrying about inductance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to isolate. It's kind of redundant since your relays are already providing isolation (for something else) so you shouldn't have to isolate your isolators. Just add flyback diodes, and maybe an R-C snubber since RC snubbers are much faster than diodes. Diodes have to turn on and clamp but don't slow rise/falltimes. RC snubbers are always on and slow/fall times but don't clamp. They hold the fort until the didoes kick in. You could also clean it at conformal coat it (I like silicone) to stop sparking, but really you shouldn't need to with flyback diodes across the relay coils.

Comment: BTW, RC snubbers are totally overkill for something like relay coils. You shouldn't need those either but since you're powering your relay coils off the same rail as your logic you may want them just in case.

Comment: I found some 1N4004's to test tomorrow. I am also considering moving the MCP to 3.3v (I have that in the board) for further isolation.

Comment: I would be checking that you actually have a reasonable stiff connection to 5V on pin 10 of the ULN2803s, if this is missing then weird shit is on the cards. Also, you do have some bulk decoupling on that board? 100uF cheap sort of electrolytic across the power input never hurts.

Comment: @Toor I tried the flyback diode – no luck. It could be that the chip is fried by now...but I decided to just redesign the board and use a bought relay board. It doesn't seem worth it to solve. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are probably multiple issues on your board. I can't speak to the sparking you're seeing, but the MCP23017 does require the address pins to be biased, according to page 11 of the datasheet:

[image]

I'm not sure if you're trying to use a specific address or not, but your software will need to reference whichever address is selected via these address pins. If you don't care what the address is, I'd just ground all three pins to use address '0100000':

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll definitely make that change. I'm not sure if that is my issue, as the MCP's address has been steady (when I've tested it with no relay). It could be causing issues though, I'll report back.